# Worksheet object declaration

Tags: excel, vba, object, variable-declaration

I've always declared a worksheet object using the syntax `Dim w as Worksheet`, but recently I came across some code that used `Dim w as Excel.Worksheet`.

I checked with the Object Browser which stated that Worksheet is a member of Excel.  So my question is why does simply `Dim ws as Worksheet` also work?

I suspect it might be that Excel objects do not require the Excel prefix, but so far I've not come across a definitive statement to that effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Excel VBA they are for all intents and purposes the same thing. Excel is the 'parent' of worksheet but it is implicitly defined within the Excel VBA workspace. In general it is not required when working within Excel VBA as it is the default.

However,if you were working within Word VBA and had imported the Microsoft Excel x.x object library, you would need to specify `Excel.Worksheet` since the Word application model would be the default and it does not contain a Worksheet type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - now that you pointed that out it stands to reason.  I don't suppose you could direct me to some documentation on thsi?  Thanks.

Comment: [You could start here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model)